# Form validation error in dynamic array in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I want to initialize a dynamic array with delete and add functionality with `useForm` method from `react-hook-form` package.

whenever i'm trying to add or delete some inputs in `react-hook-form` throwing errors for the inputs which have values.

i don't know what i'm missing here. i added my code to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dewdney-7369n?file=/src/App.js)

please have a look and help me to find out solution

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, issue is that you're trying to access courseId from props which isn't defined in App component as argument. here - data.courseId = props.courseId;

Comment: another warning is  - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.  you need to assign unique index/id as key to div whenever you map data. this warning will go away

Comment: @LakshmanKambam I think you cant get my problem please try to add or delete something and submit form you get my point

Comment: i did, can you verify the same here - https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-babbage-p84yb?file=/src/App.js  check and let me know

Comment: @LakshmanKambam yes same thing and getting same errors

Comment: can you add screenshot of errors that you're talking about in your question.

Comment: @LakshmanKambam https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pZ-TIf15oXEae7gB75lwVPvA8Pi69f_t/view?usp=sharing    have a look if you you try to delete and add input in form then click on submit you get errors

Comment: those aren't errors! it's input validation showing required fields messages

Comment: @LakshmanKambam but the inputs have their values

Comment: yeah. clarification about exact issue is important. let me check and update in same link.

Comment: @LakshmanKambam yes this issue is important